# set phpstorm working

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm

I'm trying to configure correctly phpstorm but I receive this error:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php/private/var/folders/k9/kwf7lc153rngm1ky4_3948sc0000gn/T/ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/FirstAid_jquerymobile
Testing started at 21:17 ...

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I installed phpunit but I don't even know which could be the error?

Comment: Can you run PHPUnit from the command line successfully? Start by simplifying the problem so you can localize it.

Comment: Any progress on that? What's the next step if phpunit runs at the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Usually PhpStorm produces this error when PHPUnit fails with fatal - check the PHP error log or run PHPUnit directly from CLI - it will help to localize the problem.